# Should questions about the 2017 version of Paranoia be tagged differently than older versions?

Tags: discussion, tags

The 2017 version of *Paranoia* is a pretty big departure from older versions. Instead of a single d20, perversity points, and communists, we have a pool of d6s, XP points, and terrorists. In other words, there are pretty big changes to the game mechanics and setting and a question relevant for an older version might not be relevant to this version.

Unfortunately, this new version is still called *Paranoia* and doesn't have a specific edition. So should we keep using the [paranoia](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paranoia) tag for questions about the new versions? Or should we create a new tag (and if so, what should it be)?

Comment: This isn't an issue at the moment, but I'd like to ask some questions about the new version, so it soon will be.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Questions about it should probably have a different tag, because it'll help prevent people from answering based on the wrong game, and help people find answers for the right game.

For different games with the same name, we can add a bit on the end with the most useful disambiguating phrase. E.g., [star-wars-d6](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-d6) is our tag for the game officially named *Star Wars: The Roleplaying Game*.

In this case I think [paranoia-2017](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paranoia-2017) works best, since it's clear and has a good chance of being the wider community's unofficial name for it anyway, and will likely lead to better tagging. (And if we need to change it later, that's easy if things are well-tagged.)

Comment: I also agree that it should get a new tag. Arguably it could be paranoia-2016 since that's the copyright date, but then again it didn't deliver until 2017. Likewise, rpggeek calls it "Paranoia Rebooted" but that name isn't used anywhere else, so I would not recommend it.